# Scope issue using dependency injection of a component's providers' array in Angular

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

Is it possible to provide a service to another service using the providers' array of a component?

I tried injecting the service this way, but was unsuccessful in getting this to work.

This is the component where I am providing the service.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [{ provide: EXAMPLE_TOKEN, useClass: ExampleService }]  <---- this doesn't work as expected
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

This is the component, which uses a service to which I am trying to inject the token defined above.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.css'],
})
export class ExampleComponent {
  constructor(private parentService: ParentService) { }
}
```

Here I am using the token defined in the app-component.

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ParentService {
  constructor(@Inject(EXAMPLE_TOKEN) private conf: ExampleService) { }  <---- throws error
}
```

I am trying to find a way to provide a service component wise, without using module providers. Is it possible to achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to do it, but I suppose this does not work because you are providing the `ParentService` in the `root` injector (with `providedIn: 'root'`). If you remove that, and have the `ParentService` provided in the `providers` array of the `ExampleComponent`, then your service would be provided by a component injector, and angular will traverse the component injector tree all the way up to your `AppComponent` and resolve your `EXAMPLE_TOKEN` from there. If you provide a service in the `root` injector, it will only try to resolve dependencies using the root and platform injectors.

Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class ParentService {
  constructor(@Inject(EXAMPLE_TOKEN) private conf: ExampleService) { }
}
```

Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.css'],
  providers: [ParentService],
})
export class ExampleComponent {
  constructor(private parentService: ParentService) { }
}
```

Edit:

Angular tries to resolve the `ParentService` at the element injector level (`ExampleComponent`) then navigates the tree all the way up till the root element injector (`AppComponent`) but AppComponent does not provide the `ParentService`. Then it starts traversing the module injector tree, and it finds `ParentService` in the `root` injector. But at that level (root injector level) there is no provider for `EXAMPLE_TOKEN` and that's why the initialization fails, and my answer helps. In my snippet, Angular will try to use the element injectors when creating `ParentService` and it will successfully find the `EXAMPLE_TOKEN` dependency in the root element injector.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, there is something which is not clear. Aren't in general 'ElementInjectors' traversed first before attempting to resolve 'ModuleInjectors'? You made a good point, but I don't think this solves the problem yet. Am I wrong?

Comment: You are right, I did manage to get it working, thanks so much.

Comment: @Razvan Please disregard my previous comment, I added some extra explanations in the answer itself.